# Checkbox checked if boolean is true with Angular2

Tags: html, checkbox, angular, boolean

I would like to know how to make a checkbox checked if the value is true, and unchecked if false with `Angular2`.

```
Adult <input type="checkbox" value="{{person.is_adult}}">
```

{{person.is_adult}} is a `boolean`

Can someone please suggest anything? Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`{{}}` does string interpolation and stringifies `true` and `false` and Angular by default uses property binding and I assume the property expects boolean values not strings:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="person.is_adult">
```

This might work as well

```
<input type="checkbox" attr.checked="{{person.is_adult}}">
```

because with attribute binding the browser might translate it from the attribute (which can only be strings) to boolean when reading it into its property.

It is also `checked` instead of `value`

You can also use `ngModel`

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]"person.is_adult" name="isAdult">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]"person.is_adult" name="isAdult">
```

for one-way or two-way binding.
Ensure your have the `FormsModule` imported if you use `ngModel`.

Comment: Using `value` did not work for me only `checked` worked.

Comment: Right, I didn't pay attention to the attribute name (copied from the question) but only to the mistake in the binding.

Answer (score 15):

you are missing square bracket around checked

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="person.is_adult">
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="person.is_adult">
```

**If you are using `ngModel` :**

When `ngModel` is used in a form it won't work. However, you should use `[ngModelOptions]` attribute like

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="is_adult"
  [(ngModel)]="person.is_adult"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
```