# Radio button's ng-checked attribute doesn't work in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a radio button in my Angular project

```
<input type="radio" ...  checked />
```

But if I replace **checked** property on ng-checked `ng-checked="true"` or on `ng-model="flag"` (where flag is a component's field and it equals true) 
it remains unchecked. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you add a plnkr re-creating the issue.  Also, you're using AngularJS not Angular right?

Comment: What is plnkr? I use Angular, not AngularJS

Comment: https://plnkr.co/ is where you can post running code online, it's often used to show examples.  Also if you're using Angular 2+ and not AngularJS then the syntax `ng-checked` and `ng-model` won't work since that is AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-checked` and `ng-model` is AngularJS syntax.

If you are using Angular, you have to use default HTML syntax:

```
<input type="radio" checked="true"/>
```

And binding to a property of the Component:
One-way:

```
<input type="radio" [checked]="myProperty"/>
```

or two-way:

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myProperty"/>
```

The ["Tour of Heroes" is a really good Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) to get started with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple and should work. But probably somewhere else in the code or in the controller you are changing the flag. But following works with AngularJS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">
<input type="radio" ng-checked="true"> Checked radio <br><br>
<input type="radio" ng-checked="false"> Not Checked radio <br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

But for Angular 2+ [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233130/checkbox-checked-if-boolean-is-true-with-angular2) you have to do

Comment: Thanks. But you use angularJS and my project's angular version is the last one

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think you are using Angular 2+ and trying to achieve with Angular 1.x syntax.

Comment: If that solves your issue, consider accepting the answer to help others.