# Set checkbox to checked if value is true (.ascx)

Tags: html, web, ascx

I have a problem which I can't solve.

I have a table that fills dynamically with data pulled in from DB. I send it through controller and then access it with {{variables.value}}.
For a cleaner look I decided to show the Boolean value as a checkbox. If true the checkbox should be checked otherwise unchecked.

This code has an error. The error is: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

I don't think PHP would have a problem with this but C# does. But no matter how I turn the code around I can't seem to find a way I could set checked value to a checkbox with the help of value I pull in.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxName" checked="<% ({{variables.visible}} == true ? "checked" : "") %> />
```

Also worth mentioning if I do something like the code below the data I pull in is correctly displayed so the issue is not in retrieving the data.

```
<td>
 <p>{{process_variable.visible}}</p>
</td>
```

I found [Checkbox checked if boolean is true with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233130/checkbox-checked-if-boolean-is-true-with-angular2) and it didn't work/help.

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is a boolean attribute in HTML. The presence of this attribute alone indicates that the checkbox is checked. Leave out this attribute at all to have an unchecked checkbox.

In the question you have linked, they use an Angular attribute `attr.checked` instead of an HTML attribute. The first one result in the latter one not being printed if the value is false.

I don't know what ascx stands for, but based on your code above, a possible solution might be to print the whole attribute only on true values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxName" <% ({{variables.visible}} == true ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") %> />
```

Comment: I tried exactly this as well but it doesn't work. This line of code results in 15 errors. 1-9 Missing "{" or "(" or ";"
10-14 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
15 The name 'variables' does not exist in the current context

If I put the {{variables.visible}} behind the /> works like a charm

Comment: Caved in and fixed it with Angular like in the linked question. Thanks for your help